# Newey West and paired t test to correct for autocorrelation

Tags: r

I have been looking extensively for the following.

Is there a way to use Newey West (1994) estimator for a paired T test in R?

The t.test() gives me correct t values, but then I want to correct them for autocorrelation. It seems not possible.

With coeftest() there is a way to use newey west correction, but only for independent t test and not paired t test!

```
 x <-rnorm(100)
 k <-rnorm(100)
 t.test(x,k, paired=TRUE)
```

Now let's assume I know there is autocorrelation in my data (x and k) and therefore I want to use the Newey West estimator to correct for that.

Anyone any idea to do that with t.test?

Alternatively one can use the following:

```
 fit<-lm(x~k)
 coeftest(fit)
```

This is an independent t test. Anyone any idea how to make a paired t test with coeftest()?

Next, one can embed NeweyWest estimator in the t test to adjust for autocorrelation.

```
 coeftest(fit, df=Inf, vcov=NeweyWest)
```

Again, I want to do this with a paired t test.

If anyone has any insight, please let me know.

Comment: Please elaborate your question and show us some code.

Comment: Thanks for reply. See updated question

Comment: One can sometimes create a new dependent variable that is the difference of the paired values and run a regression on the differences. Since your procedural description is so impoverished, it's not really possible to test this strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Notice any similarities? Still have not figured out the issues about which you are concerned, but I don't really agree that the the regression corresponds to independent t-test. With an ind t-test there is no item-by-item pairing, whereas in regression there most definitely is such a pairing.

```
t.test(x,k, paired=TRUE)
#--------------------
    Paired t-test

data:  x and k
t = -0.6008, df = 99, p-value = 0.5493
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.3746782  0.2005112
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
             -0.0870835 
#------------------
library(lmtest)
 fit<-lm(  (x-k) ~ 1)
 lmtest::coeftest(fit)
#------------------
t test of coefficients:

             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -0.087083   0.144941 -0.6008   0.5493
```

Comment: You are right. Thanks for clarify! I double checked and both are paired t tests. Now it is also possible to correct for autocorrelation with Newey West (1994) estimator. # coeftest(fit, vcov=NeweyWest)

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a paired t-test in regression settings by taking the difference in outcomes for each pair and regressing it on the vector of ones. Once you have cast the problem this way, it is easy to use standard functionalities from "lmtest" library in R including the NeweyWest estimator. A code snippet follows:

```
 fit<-lm(x-k~1)
```

`coeftest(fit, df=Inf, vcov=NeweyWest)`